# Where can I report a malicious app in your store?

Tags: malware

I just noticed there are three different "leger live" applications in your snap store.
Suspecting a fraud, I downloaded them, and indeed, some of them ask for the seed phrase... (which of course it should not happen!!!)
Please take them off, and explore the issue before some users lost all their crypto.

What is the process to report this?

Br,
E.

Comment: I own a snap store? That's news to me :P

Comment: Stack Overflow, Inc. does not have a snap store, nor does the Ask Ubuntu community. You will have to talk to the owner of whatever snap store you are talking about.

Comment: Saying "three different "leger live" applications" without naming them makes your Question seem useless

Answer (score 4):

On the webpage [snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io/), there is a link to report on the page of each app.